# What are "Notifications" in Trello?

Tags: trello

Trello has links to *Notifications* in a number of places but whenever I click on them it simply says

> No Notifications

What is the intended purpose of the *Notifications* and where do they come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notifications contains a list of changes that are likely to impact you or require actions.  These include:

- Getting assigned to a card
- Being mentioned in a card through an `@` message
- Having a card you're assigned to altered in a significant way (moved, archived, and so on)
- Being invited to a board

There may be other things that result in you getting a notification, but those are the ones that I see on a regular basis.

Comment: Benjamin is a member of Fog Creek Software, makers of Trello, but not part of the Trello team.

Comment: I'm having the same result. I'm subscribed to board, list, card but even with changes within the card or moving to another list, I still get no notifications.