# Will adding or removing a label to a card send a notification its members on Trello?

Tags: trello, notifications, trello-labels

Based on the list provided by in a [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/what-are-notifications-in-trello/19115) and my cursory experimentation, my assumption (though it is only that) is that any change which does not appear in the board activity log will not trigger a notification. Am I wrong, and will adding a label notify the members?

Answer (score 5):

Correct - labeling is currently considered to be a minor action that should not trigger notifications.